# Date and closest time continuous glucose monitor

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am a diabetic I can export my continuous glucose monitor blood sugars in to excel sheet, this machine checks my sugars every 5 mins. What give my doctor are snapshots thought out the day. Its normally around 8am, 10am, 12pm, 2pm, 5:30pm, 7:30, then bedtime and 3am. What I am looking to do is base this off the date, then the nearest time. 
I have been playing using the Match with Min am came close to using something like this,

INDEX(C2:C11,MATCH(MIN(ABS(B2:B8-"03:00:00")),ABS(B2:B8-"03:00:00"),0))

I can get the number if I am only looking at one date, 
what I am having issues with is trying to 1st look at the dated then fine the closest time to say 3:00:00 and give me that number at that time. Here is what it basically looks like. So on the sheet, I send my doctor I want to put the date in and pull the numbers closet to that time of day.

```
A1 Date (02/25/2018) then in B1 will read this and pull 3am then C1 8am D1 10am etc 

A2 Date (02/25/2018) then in B2 will read this and pull 3am then C2 8am D2 10am etc
```

The export looks something like this. But with 5000 lines.

```
 Date         Time      Numbers
02/25/2018  3:44:54     96
02/25/2018  3:49:54     92
02/25/2018  23:54:54    88
02/25/2018  23:59:54    86
02/26/2018  0:04:54     83
02/26/2018  0:09:54     80
02/26/2018  0:14:54     78
02/26/2018  0:19:54     76
02/26/2018  0:24:54     75
02/27/2018  2:59:52     263
02/27/2018  3:04:52     265
```

Answer (score 0):

Could try [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) and use the Approximate Match for the range_lookup option, however this does have it's limitations as noted further down.

Have your dates running down column A like the below image for example.

[image: ColumnA]

Have your times running across row 1 like the below image for example.

[image: Row1]

Formula
`=VLOOKUP(ABS(DATE(YEAR($A2),MONTH($A2),DAY($A2))+TIME(HOUR(B$1),MINUTE(B$1),SECOND(B$1))),Report!$A:$B,2,-1)`
paste that into B2 and just drag it across to the other columns.

[image: Formula]

**Please note:**

- This is not entirely accurate for example it will return `01:58:00` as being closer to `03:00:00` instead of `03:16:00` as it is the closest value not over `03:00:00`, as you can see in the below image.

[image: Data Extracted Highlighted]